# Should a single Mongoose connection be used for all requests? Or different connection for each request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm coming from SQL databases, and I'm wondering if single/multiple connections to MongoDB have any differences than SQL databases.

Are there any performance or security issues to using any of the approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Code-wise there is no problem with only connecting once to your database. What you can do however, is increase the amount of sockets/connections kept open by mongoose by specifying the `poolSize` during connection. See here [mongoose connection doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html). The default is 5. This does for example make sense, if you have a few slow queries blocking many fast queries. Also, sometimes it makes sense to create multiple database connections to separate packages/models from each other, but you should be careful not to create any race conditions like this. Finally, depending on your specification, it could also make sense to use a single connection to write and another to read from either the same or a replica/slave database to improve your performance.